# Flutter new project Fatal exit with error code 1

Tags: flutter

I have created and run successfully flutter project on my laptop, but every time when I have created a new project and run it that requires an internet connection,otherwise gives error "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

And when I connected the laptop to the internet then it will download all sdk and dependencies again

Comment: Run 'flutter doctor' command in your terminal window. Does it show any failed component?

Comment: After run "flutter doctor" No issue fond

Comment: problem is that it will download all sdk and gradle files again for new project.

Comment: 2. Have you added flutter to your environment variable? You can see here how to add environment variables - https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: The issue might be flutter is not installed properly.

Comment: yes..! i have set enviroment varible path also.but flutter doctor not showing any issue

Comment: What about you ? Do you need internet connection everytime when you create a new project and run it

Answer (score 0):

Just change gradle and gradle wrapper in these 2 files in your project :

```
android/build.gradle:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' to 4.0.2

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip to 6.4.1-all
```

This is just a workaround, still looking for a real solution